# Android. Передать "result" из onCreateView в TimerTask

Tags: java, android

В приложении нужно добиться того, чтобы была возможность листать "страницы", где на одной из них, выборочно, по нажатию кнопки запускался свой таймер.

Перелистывание "страниц" было решено осуществить с помощью VievPager

Расписываю код для ViewPager в PageFragment.java

В onCreate я написал про `result`, для того, чтобы нижеприведённая кнопка "buttonStart" была в разметке фрагмента.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Пишем про result
        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

        //Расписываю кнопку
        Button buttonStart = (Button)result.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

        //Устанавливаю Listener для кнопки
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (MyTimer != null) {MyTimer.cancel();}    //Останавливаем старый таймер, если он идёт
                MyTimer = new Timer();                      //Объявляю таймер
                MyTimerTask = new timerTask();              //Обявляю задачу для таймера
                MyTimer.schedule(MyTimerTask, 1000, 1000);  //Раписываю "шаг" таймера
            }});

        return result;
    }
```

Из кода видно, что в приложении используется таймер.

Вот сам код для таймера:

```
//Расписываю действие для таймера
    private class timerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Timercount = Timercount - 1; //Это чтобы время таймера уменьшалось

            if ( Timercount >= 0) { //Если таймер ещё идёт, то

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                            TextView countview = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.displaycount); //Объявляю TextView
                            countview.setText(Timercount); //Пишу время таймера
                        }});

            } else {                //Если время таймера подошло к концу

                if (MyTimer != null) {MyTimer.cancel();} //Останавливаем таймер, если он идёт

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        TextView countview = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.displaycount); //Объявляю TextView
                        countview.setText("Время вышло"); //Пишу "Время вышло"
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Таймер действует по классическому принципу: заранее выбранное число с каждой секундой уменьшается и демонстрируется в `countview`.

`countview` должен быть в разметке фрагмента, то есть должен использоваться `result`, объявленный ранее в onCreateView

```
TextView countview = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.displaycount);
```

Я не могу понять, как перенести `result` из onCreateView, где он прописывался, в TimerTask где он нужен. Или как его написать повторно уже в TimerTask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот эту строку

`TextView countview = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.displaycount);`

надо писать в `OnCreateView`. А правильнее - делаете глобальную переменную `TextView mCountView` в фрагменте. и в `OnCreateView`

```
 mCountView= (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.displaycount);
```

и уже с ней работаете в таймере. `result` (т.е. корень лейаута трогать вообще не стоит)

Т.е. глобальная переменная это ссылка на ваше countView. Эта вьюха всегда есть в лейауте, каждый раз делать findViewById() не надо

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "глобальной переменной"?

Comment: глобальная перменная - поле у фрагмента

Comment: кидайте лог ошибки

Comment: Вот, вроде, основная проблема: `W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000003e7`

Comment: Вылетает, когда доходит до кода: `mCountView.setText(Timercount);`

Comment: Поискав в интернете нашел решение: нужно писать `mCountView.setText(Timercount + "");`.  Это как-то тупо, но работает. Не знаете зачем  `+ ""` нужно?

Comment: @Михаил потому что `Timercount ` - это `int`. И при передаче его в `setText` происходит попытка найти ресурс с таким id.

Comment: Аа, да, точно. Спасибо, @Suvitruf. То есть можно представить как `mCountView.setText(String.valueOf(Timercount))`

Comment: @Михаил именно (: